# Check if difference between current time and a stored time value is bigger than a fixed value

Tags: sql, postgresql

The setup: a number of devices (arduino, not that it matters) connect to my database to update their current state: voltage, temperature, etc... and last_update column.

What i'm trying to do is know when a device goes offline. Meaning when current_time-last_update is superior to let's say 10 seconds (constant value), i can update "device_state" to "offline"

What's the best optimal way to do that. Best way i found is create a job that selects every minute or so all devices which last_update is older than 10 seconds. Is there a better way?

It's a monitoring system with a web frontend. I need to know in real time (or almost real time) which devices are offline.

Thanks

Comment: You can query when the last entry was made from a device and determine if it's likely offline just in time. No need to physically change any values, no need for any jobs or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this functionality using a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           ( last_update < now() - interval '10 second' ) as is_offline
    from t;
```

When you query the view, the column will automatically be updated.

Many databases support computed columns.  Postgres is not yet one of them.

There is also a method using a function that does something very similar (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166792/postgresql-generated-columns/183265) for details).